# Who is reading the file system from a USB flash drive or external storage? kernel or os?

Tags: filesystems, kernel

How can I see the steps taken and where can I see them?

What data is being taken by the OS / kernel to read the file system so that it can be used?

when the flashdrive is attached to USB, who is the first to carry out the interaction and how the filesystem on the flashdrive can be read and detected until it can be used.

Comment: What "steps" are you referring to? The kernel manages a fair bit of data stored on the block device to create a usable file system, you might want to clarify your question to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

The kernel handles all IO to the device. Most of the time the twiddling of the on-device data structures that define the filesystem are also handled by the kernel, but it is entirely possible to do that work in an userspace program. One example is the [mtools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtools) package, that allows futzing around with MS-DOS filesystems purely from userspace.

As an aside, the nicest definition of "operating system" I've seen is "whatever you get handed by your provider when you ask for an operating system". Operating system texts typically take a much more narrow view, calling just the kernel (and perhaps a bit of infrastructure code) "operating system". And the core of what makes your Linux machine usable today goes well beyond the kernel.